# Query to find intersect of data in a single table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In `MS Access 2010` I have a two-column table (publications) that includes authors' names and the year they published their articles.

```
    author   year
    Davis A  1973
    Boyd B   1973
    Davis A  1974
    Pit L    1974
...
```

I want to find the number of authors who published in two or three or N years (e.g. those who published both in `1973` and `1974` like `Davis A`). I know this could be done with SQL intersect (something like this)

```
SELECT publications.author, publications.year
FROM publications
WHERE publications.year=1973
INTERSECT
SELECT publications.author, Author_year_unique_year.year
FROM publications
WHERE publications.year=1974;
```

But Access doesn't have Intersect and the solution is apparently Join but i have only one table. Or instead of the number, if i can get the list of those authors published in N given years it would be fine as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with subqueries:

```
select years, count(*), min(author), max(author)
from (select author, count(*) as years
      from (select distinct author, year
            from publications
           ) as p
      group by author
     ) as t
group by years
order by years;
```

If you want two particular years, you can also use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select author
from publications
group by author
having sum(iif(year = 1973, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(year = 1974, 1, 0)) > 0
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of publications for an author in a given year.  The `> 0` finds authors with at least one.  This structure is quite flexible, you can readily add more years or exclude a particular year (by using `= 0` instead of `> = 0`).

Comment: Thanks. The second solution worked perfectly. For the first one I got the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression count(distinct year)"

Comment: @Hamid . . . Of course, Access doesn't support count distinct.  I'll rewrite it so it is correct.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the query just to get authors who have published ONLY in a given year (e.g. 1973) or two given years (e.g. 1973 & 1975) and not in any other years? Thanks

Comment: @Hamid . . . You would modify the `having` statement and include clauses like `and `sum(iff(year <> 1973, 1, 0)) = 0` for the first one and `sum(iff(year not in (1973, 1975), 1, 0) = 0` for the second.